# Why debug with inspect on google chrome missing show file js when i search by ctrl+p

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools, inspect

I'm dev angular when i debugging on chrome. Some time I search file with ctrl+p return null but when i add to file a line text "debugger;" i see it. What wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

From this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bwt76sk%28v=vs.94%29.aspx.

You can place debugger statements anywhere in procedures to suspend execution. Using the debugger statement is similar to setting a breakpoint in the code.

```
for(i = 1; i<5; i++) {
   // Print i to the Output window.
   Debug.write("loop index is " + i);
   // Wait for user to resume.
   debugger
}
```

So it looks like you are trying to reach a page that only in debug mode you can see when the browser stop running. In static mode it is already loaded this page and close it.

If your application started with the  login.html -> inProgress.html -> homepage.html , so if you have script on inProgress.html and this page is not visible to the user and happen only for 3 milliseconds so only in debug mode you will find this script.

Comment: My case, My js file is controller of html file. But when html file is showing, i cannot see js file. When i close and add "debugger" to first line of controller then i invisible on search